# How to shade between contour lines in ArcMap to create a two toned bathymetry map

Tags: arcmap, contour

I have a shapefile containing the contour lines for a lake. I want to colour the lake by depth above and below a depth threshold of 10 meters (i.e. blue for shallower than 10 meters and grey for deeper than 10 meters) by shading between contour lines. I have tried using the feature to polygon tool, but the contour values aren't carried over, so I cannot colour by depth.

Comment: You're trying to create hypsometric areas, these are *really* difficult to create, it would be far easier to use a DEM and slice it https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/slice.htm if you don't have access to the DEM that created the contours you can use Topo to Raster to generate a DEM from the contours https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/topo-to-raster.htm - both of these require a spatial analyst license.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you - I was able to get a spatial analyst license and make it work!